# How do you translate a manga panel into a video?

Tags: anime-production, manga-production

Let's say you have a Manga panel or a whole volume and you want to make a video of it and present every pictures in sequential order. Is there a way to do this properly? What are the various standards and methods used to do it one-by-one with as little modification as possible. I don't want to animate it, just present each image one at a time in a somewhat enjoyable video format.

Answer (score 0):

Check out any manga of your choosing on YouTube for reference.

Most people making these kinds of videos tend to sort of slowly go over each of the pages, lingering on the individual panels for varying amounts of time, based on the content.

You could try to do a video following something like this.

- Dialogue-heavy panels get more time so the viewer can read it without having to pause
- Visually heavy panels get more time so the viewer can take his time looking at the artwork
- ect.

This way you could potentially create something "somewhat enjoyable".

Ultimately, the easiest way would probably be to go over each panel long enough so the viewer can feasibly pause the video and get a clear view.